# Python str() : TypeError: 'str' object is not callable - the stop code

Tags: string, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

code can only run the first time. after that I found a mistake : `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

create :

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

berat = soup.find_all("dd", {"class": "pull-left m-0 border-none"})[0].text
var1 = str(berat)
str = string.maketrans('us', '12')
result = var1.translate(str)
print (result)
```

output error

```
Beka2
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "current.py", line 67, in <module>
var1 = str(berat)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

enough to make me confused:
I want output :
Baru = Bar1
Bekas = Beka2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you run this in Python interactive console. In this case the problem was due to your `str` variable, which created when the code run for the first time, hides the built-in function `str()` intended to be called when you run it the second time.

Just never use Python [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html) name as your variable name :

```
something_that_is_not_str = string.maketrans('us', '12')
result = var1.translate(strsomething_that_is_not_str)
print(result)
```